# Does clusterring key impact the load performance in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does putting a clustering key impact the bulk copy performance? For example if I have a large table and I am loading data into it. and it has 2 clustering key in it. does removing the clustering key helps in loading the file faster. or since clustering is an automated process, It happens in backend. say for example snowflake loads the data first and after that it does the clustering in backend while data is already available to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not affect bulk copy performance.

> since clustering is an automated process, It happens in backend. say
> for example snowflake loads the data first and after that it does the
> clustering in backend while data is already available to use.

Yes, it is exactly how it works.

Comment: In that case, if somebody execute a query straight away after loading then their might be a chance of getting the data from un-clustered table.. right?

Comment: yes, reclustering may take time.